# What's up with Community Wiki

Tags: support, community-wiki

Note: I thought I saw this discussed, but couldn't find it.

We have a fair number of "what are some blogs|podcasts|web sites|books" questions that should definitely (IMO) be community wiki.

What I haven't figured out is how we mark questions for community wiki? As far as I can tell, there's no way to do it by editing a question, nor a way select community wiki when *asking* a question. I know other sites have community wiki - is this something that gets turned on later, or has something changed/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my meta post about it:

[Where did the CW flag go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90654/where-did-the-cw-flag-go)

Bottom line is: only moderators can force a question to be community wiki. Answers can be made community wiki by their authors (or by editors, I believe.) Questions can be converted into community wiki by the system if there are too many edits within a particular period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Because of wide-spread confusion and misuse of the community wiki setting, community wiki for *QUESTIONS* has been scaled back considerably ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67581/community-wiki-checkbox-missing-in-action)).

Questions can no longer be set to community wiki, except by a moderator. If you feel that a question really needs to be community wiki, you can flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.